# Fixing black faces in texture after using dyntopo

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, artifacts

Lately I have encountered a problem while sculpting a model created using photogrammetry. When I was using dyntopo to fix areas with wrong topology, newly created faces didn't dynamically unwrap and because of it there are black, not unwrapped spots on my mesh.[image: vis] What I tried to do was using clone brush, but as you may have guessed it didn't work at all because of the texture islands being randomly spread in the image. Also there is a significant part of environment textures which are useless and occupy image space. Here is one of four images used for texturing (just to show what they all look like, posting an image which is the most light-weight): [image: vis2] I'd be grateful for any tips on how to fix these black spots.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd steer clear of using Dyntopo to fix something unless it is in a stage before modeling with retopology on the surface of the dyntopo sculpt and then using a multiresolution modifier to resculpt after the texture and model detail is already repaired. Dyntopo isn't going to magically adopt the UV info around it, as it actually breaks the UV and other info. That would be easier to retopo a new model on top of your hires model and then bake the texture from the photogrammetry textures, and then go about sculpting fine detail,

Comment: You're right unfortunately. I'll have to redo the cleaning I guess. Not that big deal though. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed a workaround exactly for this (I also use meshroom by the way). Before you fix the topology with Dyntopo, create a backup of your mesh. When you are finished painting in the polygons, you can rebake the color information from the original mesh to the Dyntopo'd one.